# How to set a different theme for editing one's account

Tags: 6, users

I read somewhere that editing account information can be done a different theme or in the admin theme but can't for the life of me find it neither on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should install and check out the administration theme module - http://drupal.org/project/admin_theme

We have used it to show the admin theme on certain urls, like the user edit page.

Here is a description from the project page:

The Administration theme module allows you to use this theme on more pages like :
- batch processing pages
- devel node load and render pages
- coder code review pages
- pages you define yourself in the provided textarea

Hope that helps

Comment: Does the trick beautifully

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `admin/settings/admin` you can select your admin theme as well as using it for content editing.

Comment: Hi yes this sets a bunch of administration pages and content editing pages to the default admin theme but unfortunately not the user account editing pages.